# Javascript not Executing on Github

Tags: javascript, python, github, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code to add a table of contents to the beginning of my ipython notebooks. When I run the cell on jupyter on my computer I get

[image]

But when I upload the notebook to github and choose to view the notebook, I see this for the first cell.

[image]

Is there a way to enforce that this javascript line runs like the first picture when on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Is there a way to enforce that this javascript line runs like the first picture when on github?"*

...No, Github is not designed for this. You can't **run** code on it. It's only for sharing purposes. If you want to **run** code on a website, upload it to either [CodePen](https://codepen.io/), [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there would be a way to get a table of contents for notebooks when uploaded to github then? Like you said, its about code sharing, and a table of contents at the beginning of jupyter notebooks really helps with that,

Comment: No, I don't think so. Because the links in the table link to places **within** the Jupiter notebook. A better idea would be to just share the notebook on the Microsoft Azure website, where the notebooks are created anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles upon this in the future, there is a solution. Github won't run the javascript extensions in a .ipynb file, but that is what nbviewer is used for. Simply enter in the URL of a file on github into the nbviewer main website.

For example, examine how the table of contents javascript extension (first cell) runs on nbviewer

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/lukepolson/Python-Self-Learning/blob/master/Matplotlib_2-Additional_Features.ipynb

but not on github

https://github.com/lukepolson/Python-Self-Learning/blob/master/Matplotlib_2-Additional_Features.ipynb